# In major can ii V I support ^6 ^7 ^8?

Tags: chord-progressions, voice-leading

Is there any reason why this progression should be a problem in major keys? The other harmonizations I have for this soprano according to "Harmony and Voice Leading" by Edward Aldwell and Carl Schachter are:

- vi V I,
- IV vii6 I,
- IV vii6 I6

They don't include ii V I however and I think this is an obvious choice unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Other than IV V I, it's hard to think of a more idiomatic ending than the one you're describing.  You're quite right.

Comment: @Bennyboy melodies of the 18th century typically cadence from above, though, or, if not, as ^8 ^7 ^8 or ^9 ^7 ^8, so ^6 ^7 ^8 is more likely to be found in the middle of a phrase.  For an ^8 ^7 ^8 cadence you're likely to find ii7 V I or, more likely, ii(6/5) V I.  The latter also works for ^9 ^7 ^8, as does ii6 V I.

Comment: Have I missed a criterion?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I'm just saying that having ^6 ^7 ^8 in the soprano isn't a particularly idiomatic ending in the 18th century.

Answer (score 3):

That's interesting; there's nothing that would prevent ii–V–I from harmonizing this 6–7–1 soprano line.

A similar progression, though, *would* present a problem: IV–V–I would almost certainly lead to parallel octaves (see A, below), parallel fifths (see B), *or* a doubled leading tone (see C), and so it makes sense that IV–V–I is not included. But ii–V–I doesn't have these problems (see D).

[image]

My guess is that this is a byproduct of the authors' Schenkerian-theory mindset. In Schenkerian theory, the best tonal closure occurs with a *descending* soprano line of something like 3–2–1. As such, a firm cadence like ii–V–I is best harmonized with a soprano of 2–2–1. Notice that the sample progressions you gave for 6–7–1 are not true cadences, with the exception of vi–V–I. But this one is so comparatively rare in this style that I'm guessing they felt comfortable including it anyway.

Comment: I couldn't make the ii-V-I work in 4-part harmony. However by varying the number of voices, ii-V43-I6 works pretty well (or ii-V43-I with doubled root.)

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yes the IV V I progression is mentioned in the same section of the book as being the the wrong choice for ^6 ^7 ^8.

Comment: @armani ii6 V I is quite common in the early 18th century.

Comment: @phoog More common than IV–V–I, in my experience!

Comment: Well yes, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: @phoog... when you say common did you mean as a general cadential progression or to harmonize the soprano ^6 ^7 ^8?

Comment: @armani I meant in general.  As I've noted in another comment, final melodic cadences of ^6 ^7 ^8 are not very common.  You will often see it in an inner voice, however, with ^4 ^5 ^1 in the bass and ^2 ^2 ^1 in the soprano.

Comment: @phoog yes but its nice to use it in the middle of a phrase or section and I do like the sound of it so I was interested to know why it wouldnt have been included as a legitimate way to harmonize that line.. maybe, perhaps possibly it is because the minor version doesnt work since ii in minor is generally avoided...but even then ii6 is an option so not sure

Comment: @armani it's typical to avoid cadential harmonizations in the middle of phrases even if they could fit, because, well, it's not the end of the phrase. I looked at a couple of Bach chorales that contain ^6 ^7 ^8, one of which is _Wachet auf_ from BWV 140, where the ^8 is harmonized with a vi chord. The only example I found where it's in a I chord is _Ein feste Burg_ ("A mighty fortress") from BWV 80, where the chords are IV vii°6 I (the bass is ^4 ^2 ^1).  There's probably a Bach chorale somewhere that harmonizes those three pitches either as ii6 V I or ii V I; I just couldn't find it.

Comment: @phoog I disagree with that because a phrase could end once on the less strong cadence and then the second time on the strong cadence. This could create contrast in a nice way. Thanks for digging into the Bachlopedia :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133984/discussion-between-phoog-and-armani).

Comment: @armani there are a lot of erudite answers here, but nobody has really accepted that the answer is "Yes, you can do that."  Those chords do, in fact, work fine to support ^6^7^8, and you can write that out pretty simply to prove it to yourself.  Unless you're trying to emulate a Bach chorale, or to conform to the edicts of the theorists of the 19th and 20th century, you're fine.  We see the same thing in English grammar, where a schoolmaster might beat a student for ending a sentence with a preposition, but without actually furnishing a sensible reason why one ought not do so.

Answer (score 3):

According to Walter Piston there is a difference in basic voice leading for `ii V` compared to other descending fifth progressions...

[image]

Just to have text to accompany the image...

> In the progression II-V, it is customary not to repeat the common tone but to move the three upper voices down to the next available position.

Piston does not say why it is customary. But think the point must be about cadential harmony. Using wide open voicing to make the voices easier to read, Piston's customary treatment is...

[image]

...notice how `RE` descends to `DO` (via `TI`) and `FA` descends to `MI` (via `RE`) which provides a very strong resolution, a perfect authentic cadence.

If the basic voice leading of *hold common tones, move other tones the smallest distance* is followed the result is...

[image]

...an imperfect cadence and `FA` ascending rather that descending.

Obviously neither offends a sense of good voice leading, but one is clearly a stronger cadence. That leads me to believe Piston's point about custom must be particularly about cadential harmony. If such a progression of `ii V I` were occurring in something like a non-cadential, sequential passage, I suppose either voice leading option might be used.

Maybe the author of your book takes a view similar to Piston's.

Piston illustrated his book with a lot of examples from the great composers, but not in the voice leading principles section. Also, even though he provides lots of real music examples he didn't do anything like a *corpus analysis* as seems popular now in the computer era. I don't really know if Piston's "custom" would hold up under a large survey of real music. Regardless, the cadential aspect of the voice leading options seem clear enough and should probably be treated accordingly.

If it isn't clear, the tenor line in my examples would be the soprano line you're concerned about. You would just invert voices to put those tenor lines into the soprano position. I voiced my examples with `D` in soprano to make the cadential point clear.